# Stack Overflow exception on Many to Many relationships in Child entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have Product Entity which is associated with Category with ManyToOne Relationship

```
public class Product {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "category", nullable = false)
        @JsonIgnore
        private Category category;
    }
```

Now Category entity has Many to Many Relationship with Brand Entity.

```
public class Brand {
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productCompanyList")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Category> categories;
}

public class Category {
    @ManyToMany
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Brand> Brands;
}
```

and finally Purchase Model refers to Product

```
public class Purchase {
       @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
       private Product product;
   }
```

When i run the below Code, it is throwing Stack overflow Exception as it is recursively fetching Category and brand infinitely.

```
List<Purchase> collect = purchaseList.stream()
                .map(a -> {
                    Product p = this.Productrepo.getById(a.getProduct().getId()).orElse(null); 
               a.setProduct(p);
                    System.out.println(p);
                    return a;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please let me know is there a way to solve this issue or i have to restructure my code.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that will create a StackOverflow exception even in cases where you create simple POJO and does not has any involvement with the database. A simple workaround for these scenarios is to use `List<Identifier>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

ManyToMany requires a mapping table. The code should look like

```
@Entity
public class Brand {
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "brands")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Category> categories;
}

@Entity
public class Category {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Category_Brand", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id") }
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Brand> brands;
}
```

mappedBy must point to a field in the other entity.

Answer (score 0):

This was the first issue which I ran into while mapping Many to Many Relationship with Hibernate and sadly it **nothing to do with Entity Mapping**.

Let's forget the Hibernate for a moment and verify the class structure.

Product that has a Category `private Category category;`
Category has a list of Brands `List<Brand> Brands;`
Brand has a list of Categories `List<Category> categories;`

When you do `System.out.println(p);` it calls p.toString()
This means it makes call to `category.toString()`,
This then makes call to `Brands.toString()`
Each brand has a list of Categories so `categories.toString()` is called.
Now each category a list of Brands so `brands.toString()` is called.
And the cycle continues.

I understand that you've used `@JsonIgnore` to avoid this problem while Serializing the object but while doing toString() recursive calls are being made.

There may be other ways of addressing this but below are the two ways I solved it:

- **Override the `toString()` method and exclude the list**

You can explicitly override the `toString()` method & exclude the list from being part of the String retuned by the default toString()

- **Annotate your the fields with [`@ToString.Exclude`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/ToString.Exclude.html) lombok**

If you are using lombok to generate toString(), you can annotate these lists with [`@ToString.Exclude`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/ToString.Exclude.html) to exclude it from being part of the String retuned by the toString() method generated by Lombok.

```
public class Brand {
   @ToString.Exclude    
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productCompanyList")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Category> categories;
}

public class Category {
    @ManyToMany
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Brand> Brands;
}
```